# AngularJS UI-router not routing on Unauthorized resolve call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a dashboard app user needs to login to. Everything works correctly if you go to the login page and then login and it proceeds to the dashboard. My issue is that when some one tries to hit the dashboard view before logging in. It recognizes that the resolve call is Unauthorized 401 but it never transitions to the login page.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            authenticate: false
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',

            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
                },
                'current-status-module@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'current-status/current-status.html'
                },
                'alerts-module@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'alerts/alerts.html',
                    controller: 'AlertCardsCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        ZonesService: 'ZonesService',
                        userZones: function (LoginService, ZonesService, $stateParams) {
                            return ZonesService.query({zoneId: $stateParams.zoneId}).then(function(data){
                                return data;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                'alert-cards-module@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'alerts/alert-cards/alert-cards.html'
                },
                'zones-module@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'zones/zones.html'
                },
                'map-grid-module@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'zones/zone-map/zone-map.html'
                }
            },
            authenticate: true
        })




.factory('LoginService', function ($window, $http, $q, $state, ENV) {
    return {
        login: function (username, password) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(ENV.web_api_url + ENV.api_version + '/login', {}, {
                "headers": {
                    "X-Auth-Username": username,
                    "X-Auth-Password": password
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
                deferred.resolve(data);
                $state.transitionTo("dashboard");
            }).error(function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            //==TODO: Call endpoint to check auth token
            return true;
        },
        isRestricted: function () {
            return ENV.is_restricted;
        },
        logout: function (error) {
            // User isn’t authenticated
            $window.sessionStorage.notification = "Authenticated session has expired. Please log in again.";
            $window.sessionStorage.notifyAlert = 'show';
            $window.location = ENV.location_path_home;
        }
    }
});


.run(function ($window, $rootScope, $state, LoginService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.user = angular.fromJson($window.sessionStorage.user);
        $rootScope.loggedIn = $window.sessionStorage.loggedIn;

        if (toState.authenticate && !LoginService.isAuthenticated()) {
            // User isn’t authenticated
            $state.transitionTo("login");
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if (toState.restricted && LoginService.isRestricted()) {
            console.log("restricted...")
            // Action is restricted to user
            $rootScope.selectedIndex = 0;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition wont be true: (toState.authenticate && !LoginService.isAuthenticated())

Because you always return true in LoginService.isAuthenticated(). So,             $state.transitionTo("login") never be executed.